# AMotionEvent_getButtonState returns 0 for every button during mouse button release

Tags: c, android-ndk, mouse

I'm trying to get mouse events in a NativeActivity Application.

But in the case `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE`, `AMotionEvent_getButtonState` returns 0 for everything

In the `handle_app_input` callback, I have the following:

```c
// LOGI is a macro for logging to Logcat

int32_t handle_app_input(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event)
{
    int32_t event_type = AInputEvent_getType(event);
    
    switch(event_type)
    {
        case AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION:
        {
            int32_t motion_input_action = AMotionEvent_getAction(event);
            int32_t event_pointer_index = (motion_input_action & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            motion_input_action &= AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK;
            
            switch(motion_input_action)
            {
                case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
                {
                    int32_t mouse_button_state = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);
                    LOGI("Mouse Button Press: %d", mouse_button_state);
                    
                    break;
                }
                case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE:
                {
                    int32_t mouse_button_state = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);
                    LOGI("Mouse Button Release: %d", mouse_button_state);                   
                    
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the case `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS`, `AMotionEvent_getButtonState` returns appropriately.

But in the case `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE`, `AMotionEvent_getButtonState` returns 0 for everything

When I press the mouse button,
`Mouse Button Press: 1` gets logged

But when I release the mouse button
`Mouse Button Press: 1` doesn't get logged!

Instead I get `Mouse Button Press: 0`

Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong function:

> `AMotionEvent_getButtonState`
> Get the button state of all buttons that are pressed.

When a button is released, it is no longer pressed, so you get 0 as the result.

You should probably be using `AMotionEvent_getActionButton` instead:

> `AMotionEvent_getActionButton`
> Get the action button for the motion event.
> Returns a valid action button when the event is associated with a button press or button release action.

---

Another alternative might be to save the value of `AMotionEvent_getActionButton` from the `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS` event, and compare it against the value you get when `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE` occurs:

```
case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS: {
    // pressed_buttons is a global/instance variable which keeps its value across multiple handle_app_input invocations.
    pressed_buttons = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);
    ...
    break;
}
case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE: {
    int32_t button_state = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);
    // Calculate which buttons have gone from being pressed to not pressed.
    int32_t released_buttons = (button_state ^ pressed_buttons) & pressed_buttons;
    pressed_buttons = button_state;
    ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Okay, But `AMotionEvent_getActionButton` is available after Android API Level 33. I'm using Android API Level 30.

Comment: Well, in that case maybe you can deduce which button(s) have been released by saving the value of `getButtonState` from the PRESS event and comparing it against the value from the RELEASE event.

Comment: Hmm, Okay Thank You. If you can please provide a simple example for that in your original answer.